# Provisioning publishing pages with custom webparts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution, publishing, provisioning

I have a sandboxed solution where i provision publishing pages with custom web parts. Like this:

```
    <Module Name="CustomPage" Url="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\SPS">
<File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Draft">
  <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Pages" />
  <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400bca78471fb4d425b8218395e2f243d8b" />
  <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout"
                 Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/SummaryLinks.aspx, /_catalogs/masterpage/SummaryLinks.aspx" />
  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="TopColumnZone" WebPartOrder="0">
    <![CDATA[<webParts><webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">  <metaData><type name="Test.Test, '$' SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName '$' "  />     <Solution SolutionId="xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />        <importErrorMessage>'$'Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage></metaData>  <data><properties><property name='Title'>CustomTitle</property><property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property><property name="Description" type="string"></property>         <property name="TheURL" type="string"></property><property name="Caption" type="string"></property><property name="IframeContent" type="string"></property><property name="VideoHeight" type="int">315</property><property name="VideoWidth" type="int">420</property></properties></data></webPart></webParts>]]></AllUsersWebPart>   </File>
```

Everything works as expected in SharePoint 2010,  in SharePoint 2013 the custom properties of the web part are not populated! Anyone who can tell me how it can work in SharePoint 2013??